# How can I Simplify this code of Laravel 8?

Tags: laravel, simplify

I have this code in routes, is it possible to simplify it?
Thanks

```
Route::get('/post1', function () { 
    return view("post1");
})->name("/post1");
```

Comment: There's no complexity in this code what's the purpose of simplify what's already simple?

Comment: i would suggest reading the routing documentation again, there is a method to create a route definition that just returns a view ... `Route::view`  ... also if you are looking for 'code review' type of stuff or 'rewrite my code' things there are other sites on this network for that

Comment: you could use `Route::view('post1', 'post1')`. more here https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#view-routes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is **nothing wrong with that code**, the only way you can "simplify" that code, better to say **"abstract it"** is by **creating a controller** with a method that returns the view.

In your case, if your route is very specific you can create a **single action controller** with the command:

`php artisan make:controller PostController -i`.

Then in the controller:

```php
public function __invoke(Request $request)
{
    return view("post1");
}
```

And in your routes file:

```php
Route::post('/post1', PostController::class);
```

More info [in the Single Action Controller docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#single-action-controllers)
and in the [views docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/views#introduction)